# Sliding sidebar opens underneath content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to get this sidebar to work, but when I open it via the hamburger menu in a smaller screen, the sidebar opens underneath the content. How can I fix this? I tried following a tutorial to create this sidebar, but apparently I messed something up when I tried adding my own stuff and I'm not sure what to do. I've been playing around with elements in CSS, but it still comes out the same way.

[Screenshot of sidebar issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDXJL.png)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Fire Sans", sans-serif;
}

.app {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(../site/images/bg2.jpeg);
}

.sidebar {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
  background-color: #053853;
}

.sidebar h3 {
  color: #f6da9b;
  font-size: 0.75 rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.sidebar .menu {
  margin: 0 -1rem;
}

.sidebar .menu .menu-item {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.2 linear;
}

.sidebar .menu .menu-item:hover,
.sidebar .menu .menu-item.is-active {
  color: #3bba9c;
  border-right: 5px solid #3bba9c;
}

.content {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  padding: 2rem;
  margin: 4rem;
  width: 60%;
  border: 3px solid #e9d397;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}

.content h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.content p {
  color: #fff;
}

.menu-toggle {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 2rem;
  right: 2rem;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 99px;
  background-color: #2e3047;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hamburger {
  position: relative;
  top: calc(50% - 2px);
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 32px;
}

.hamburger > span,
.hamburger > span::before,
.hamburger > span::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: 99px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition-duration: 0.25s;
}

.hamburger > span::before {
  content: "";
  top: -8px;
}

.hamburger > span::after {
  content: "";
  top: 8px;
}

.menu-toggle.is-active .hamburger > span {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.menu-toggle.is-active .hamburger > span::before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
.menu-toggle.is-active .hamburger > span::after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  .sidebar {
    max-width: 200px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .menu-toggle {
    display: block;
  }
  .content {
    padding: 2rem;
    margin-top: 8rem;
  }
  .sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: -300px;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
    transition: 0.2 linear;
  }
  .sidebar.is-active {
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Responsive Sidebar</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style3.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="app">

    <div class="menu-toggle">
      <div class="hamburger">
        <span></span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <aside class="sidebar">
      <h3>Javascript</h3>
      <nav class="menu">
        <a href="#" class="menu-item is-active">Home</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">Week 1</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">Week 2</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">Week 3</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">Week 4</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">Week 5</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">Week 6</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">Week 7</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">Week 8</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">Week 9</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item">Week 10</a>
      </nav>
    </aside>

    <main class="content">
      <h1>Welcome, Human!</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores aliquid impedit tenetur nam, vitae fugiat doloremque ut incidunt inventore quam qui laboriosam! Esse recusandae a inventore aliquam! Distinctio, expedita hic?</p>
    </main>
  </div>

  <script>
    const menu_toggle = document.querySelector('.menu-toggle');
    const sidebar = document.querySelector('.sidebar');
    menu_toggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
      menu_toggle.classList.toggle('is-active');
      sidebar.classList.toggle('is-active');
    })
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try giving your sidebar a higher [z-index](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) than the content?

```
.sidebar {
   z-index: 2;
}

.content {
   z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much! I need to learn more about z-index; I haven't really used it before. I knew there had to be a simple answer. I still have a lot to learn. lol